# How to upload Multiple Images in Laravel web page?

Tags: laravel

It uploads multiple images in database with below code as well as in admin panel but the problem is the images does not appear in laravel web page means it displays one image replace another image. Pls anyone can help me.

**CMS Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $ginput = [];
            if($request->hasFile('gallery')){
                $files = $request->file('gallery');
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    
                    $ginput[] = ImageUpload::upload('/upload/cms',$file);
                     
                }
                $input['gallery'] = implode(',', $ginput);
            }
    }
```

**Form.blade**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <p>Gallery Image</p>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                  <input type="file" name="gallery_multiple[]"  class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                </div><br><br>
                <p class="text-center">- OR -</p>
              </div>
              @if(isset($cms) && !empty($cms->gallery))
                <?php
                  $galleryArray = explode(',', $cms->gallery);
                ?>
    
                @if(!empty($galleryArray) && count($galleryArray) > 0)
                  @foreach($galleryArray as $gallery)
                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-4 gallery-image-parent">
                      <input class="upload property-image-input" type="hidden"  value="{{ $gallery }}">
                      <div class="fuzone">
                        <div class="fu-text" style="margin: 0px;height: 100%;">
                           <img src="{{ asset('/upload/cms/'.$gallery) }}" class="property-image-preview">
                        </div>
                        <i style="background-color: red; color: #fff; height: 30px !important; width: 30px !important; border-radius: 50% !important; padding-top: 5px !important; position: relative !important; top: -160px !important; right: -92px !important;" class="fa fa-trash-o gallery-image-remove" data-page-type="{{ !isset($cms) ? 'create' : 'edit' }}" data-id="{{ $cms->id }}" data-image-name="{{ $gallery }}" style="font-size: 20px;top: -165px;"></i>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  @endforeach
                @endif
```

Comment: What is the output of `$cms->gallery`?

Comment: when i debug there is no output of $cms->gallery.

Comment: when i upload two images in web page it shows broken icon.

Comment: does anything stored in the database?

Comment: Yes, when i submit multiple images it stored in database but not appear in web page.